# Permittee and Permitter?

Tags: suffixes, is-it-a-word, agent-noun-suffix, er-ee

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/permittee), *permittee* is the one who receives a permit. May I call the one who permit something as *permitter*?

Comment: Not Wik **i** tionary, but  Wiktionary.

Comment: Is there a reason you looked up the one word but not the other?

Comment: @RegDwigнt I'm trying to find a proper name for a field of the database schema I'm working on. English isn't my mother language since I'm a Chinese. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/permitter), you can.

> **permitter** (*plural* **permitters**)
>
> One who permits.